# how can i render a component with condition in path in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i want to render a component with a condition in path prop in Route component. think of this: i want to say if path prop in Route component is `/hello1` or `/hello2` or `/hello3`and just if the path is one of these address render component `</Hello>`. something like this:

```
if(path === '/hello1' || path === '/hello2' || path === '/hello3') render component </Hello>
```

but in path prop in Route component. is there a way to do this in path prop or not? if not what is the best way to render a component with condition base on the path prop? thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by creating an array of paths and mapping through them as follows:

```js
{["hello1", "hello2", "hello3"].map((route) => (
   <Route
     key={route}
     path={route}
     element={<div>Hello component</div>}
   />
))}
```

Whatever path you add to the array, the same component will be rendered for those paths.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is kind of change of params

`<Route path="/hello/:helloId" element={<Hello/>} />`

you can pass in every thing you wanna pass  for `helloId` and it will render `Hello component`